# How to remove default padding from navigationbar (trailing)

Tags: swiftui

I'm adding some buttons to the navigationbar in SwiftUI and because I need to add some padding to them, they are displayed more to the left than I intend (as seen below).

[image]

I can fix this if I remove the individual padding from each button, but in that case the tap area is very limited and unusual from an UX perspective.

Is there a way to remove the default extra padding?

```
.navigationBarItems(
        trailing:
            HStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 0) {
                Button(action: {

                }) {
                    Image(systemName: "trash")
                    .imageScale(.large)
                    .accessibility(label: Text("Delete"))
                    .padding()
                }

                Button(action: {

                }) {
                    Image(systemName: "square.and.arrow.up")
                    .imageScale(.large)
                    .accessibility(label: Text("Share"))
                    .padding()
                }

                CustomEditButton() {
                    if self.mode?.wrappedValue == .active {
                        return self.triggerSave()
                    } else {
                        return true
                    }
                }
            }
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

try this (copy - paste - run)

```
import SwiftUI

struct DestinationView: View {
    let txt: String
    var body: some View {
        Text(txt)
            .navigationBarTitle(txt)
        .navigationBarItems(trailing:
            HStack {
                Button(action: {
                    print("tap trasgh")
                }) {
                    Image(systemName: "trash")
                }
                Button(action: {
                    print("tap in")
                }) {
                    Image(systemName: "square.and.arrow.down")
                }
                Button(action: {
                    print("tap out")
                }) {
                    Image(systemName: "square.and.arrow.up")
                }
            }.imageScale(.large).padding(.vertical, 8).padding(.horizontal, 3)//.border(Color.blue)
        )
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                NavigationLink(destination: DestinationView(txt: "Destination 1")) {
                    Text("Destination 1")
                }
                NavigationLink(destination: DestinationView(txt: "Destination 2")) {
                    Text("Destination 2")
                }
            }
        }.navigationBarTitle("title")
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: The space between the two elements is not sufficient. They are too close together from a UX pov. Vertical padding helps, but it's not enough

Comment: @AndreiMatei apply .border around each item without and with padding to be able to see what happens there. there is small bug in default positioning, most likely it will be solved in next release of SwiftUI.

Comment: yeap, looking forward to the next release :). I keep finding annoyances.

Answer (score 1):

I would use `.padding(.trailing)` for "Delete" and "Share" buttons, and don't use any padding for `CustomEditButton` at all.

And here is result

[image: demo]

Comment: tried that, the problem is with the "tappable area" it will be less for the CustomEdit button. I found it annoying to tap near the button and not see any effect

Comment: @AndreiMatei, you can use custom padding, eg. `.padding(4)` for all edges, or `.padding([.leading, .trailing], 4)`, etc. to specify for CustomEdit, or any other.

Comment: I have checked the answer, but I find it only as a workaround. The space between the two elements is not sufficient. They are too close together from a UX pov.

Answer (score 0):

I found the below workaround that suits my needs. It's not perfect, but at least the tappable area is sufficient and it's looks decent.

[image]

```
HStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 0) {
     Button(action: {
          ////
     }) {
          Image(systemName: "trash")
              .imageScale(.large)
              .accessibility(label: Text("Delete"))
              .padding(.vertical)
              .padding(.horizontal, 8)
     }

     Button(action: {
          ////
     }) {
          Image(systemName: "trash")
              .imageScale(.large)
              .accessibility(label: Text("Delete"))
              .padding(.vertical)
              .padding(.horizontal, 8)
     }

     Button(action: {
          ////
     }) {
          Image(systemName: "trash")
              .imageScale(.large)
              .accessibility(label: Text("Delete"))
              .padding(.vertical)
              .padding(.leading, 8)
              .padding(.trailing, 4)
     }
}
```